# Probability in quantum mechanics and spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin

Let A and B be two Hermitian operators in a two dimensional space, such that:
$A | \psi_{i} \rangle = a | \psi_{i} \rangle$, $B | \rho_{i} \rangle = b | \rho_{i} \rangle $

In which $\psi _{1} = (3 \rho _{1} + 4 \rho_{2})/5, \psi _{2} = (4 \rho _{1} - 3 \rho _{2})/5$

If initially a particle is in the state $\psi_{1}$, and so we measure B, and immediately after that we measure A, what is the prob that the particle is in $\psi_{1}$ again?

Now I just thought that the answer would be:

0.36 $ \langle \psi_{1} | \rho_{1} \rangle ² + 0.64 \langle \psi_{1} | \rho_{2} \rangle ² = 0.539$

But the answer is 0.64, is the given answer wrong?

Anyway, the fact that it is not 1 means that A and B don't commute, right?

Comment: All $|\psi_i\rangle$ states have the same eigenvalue of operator A? All $|\rho_i\rangle$ states have the same eigenvalue of operator B?  And what does this have to do with spin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last statement is true, and at variance with your certainly malformed first sentence. If the eigenvalues of A and B are the same for up and down components, they are both proportional to the identity, so of course they commute.

I believe what you *meant* to write is eigenvalues $A | \psi_{i} \rangle = a_i | \psi_{i} \rangle$, $B | \rho_{i} \rangle = b_i | \rho_{i} \rangle $, and that  you measure *B*  to be 0.8.

Note the orthogonal change of basis from the *ρ* states to the *ψ*  states,
$$
O_{ij}= O^T_{ij}=O^{-1}_{ij}=|\psi_i\rangle\langle \rho_j|~~.
$$
If either *A* or *B* were proportional to the identity in its own eigenbasis, it  would therefore also be such in the other basis, and would commute with the other operator, so the *B* measurement would be pointless: it would give you the same answer, which is no answer. It would not project your state to a specific *ρ* state.

If, on the other hand, you measured *B* to be 0.8, your measurement projected your state to $|\rho_2\rangle$, and you'd find
$$
|\langle \psi_1|\rho_2\rangle|^2=0.8^2~~~.
$$

I have no idea where your mystery wrong outcome came from. It should have been 1.

Comment: Actually the sentence is like a wrote, "we measure B". Thinking again, maybe the author wrote it wrong, and in fact should be 0.8. Thank you :) And, yes, my last account was rather confuse, i apologize.